# summation equation

Tags: summation, examples-counterexamples, summation-method

Do we have $\sum\sum x_i x_{i+j}= \sum x_j \sum x_i$, where $i,j$ are integers ranging from negative to positive infinity? I find this equation intuitively reasonable, but am not sure if there are some counter-examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: If the double sum is absolutely convergent, then it's true. Otherwise, it might be false.